# Frame with picture

Tags: tikz-pgf, tcolorbox

I want to create a box like this

```
 \begin{tikzpicture}
        \fill[color=blue!15, rounded corners=5pt] (0,0) rectangle ++(0.75\linewidth,-3.2);
        \draw[line width = 2pt, color=blue, rounded corners=5pt, line cap=round] (0,0) |- ++(0.75\linewidth,-3.2) -- ++(0,0.2);
        \node (Calc) at (-0.1,0.1)
            {\rotatebox{90}{\textbf{Méthode}}\hspace{.5em}
            \includegraphics[scale=0.12]{calculatrice}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

and write inside. 
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange! I suggest to have a look at the `tcolorbox` package. Or the `bclogo` package (the documentation of the later is in French)

Comment: @samcarter: It's tagged with `tcolorbox` already by the O.P.  ;-) Basically this is a duplicate, but I am too lazy to look for other questions, something with an overlay and placing the node at `frame.north west`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Ah, I did not look at the tags :)

Comment: @habib P.S. Can you please choose an English title for your question?

Comment: I'm sorry but I do not know how to change the title

Comment: "Frame with picture"

Comment: @habib Have a look in the `tcolorbox` manual, the pages 152 ff may have some useful examples http://texdoc.net/show.php?pkg=tcolorbox

Answer (score 5):

This could be a solution with `tcolorbox`. As Christian Hupfer suggested is just a regular `tcolorbox` with an overlayed node on `frame.north west`.

The used calculator is taken from [openclipart.org](https://openclipart.org/detail/150499/calculatrice).

I had to add `\usetikzlibrary{babel}` due to problems with `label` when I've declared the `tcolorbox` inside a `\newtcolorbox`, while doing tests with a `\begin{tcolorbox}` it was not needed.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}

\newtcolorbox{methode}[1][]{%
    notitle, 
    toprule=0pt, 
    rightrule=0pt, 
    colframe=blue, 
    colback=blue!15, 
    enhanced, 
    overlay={%
        \node[label={[rotate=90,anchor=south]left:Méthode}] 
        at (frame.north west) 
        {\includegraphics[scale=.12]{calculatrice}};},
    #1
}

\begin{document}
\begin{methode}
\lipsum[1]
\end{methode}
\end{document}
```

[image]